# How to prevent same selected values in multiple drop down lists in a table & POST to server

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-select, dropdown

**Example**: imagine a `table of babies`, *with each row users selects baby GenderDropDown*, then Selects a name. I need to prevent duplicate name selection across the table, If user select Male & John, he cannot select that again in another row. **Except babies, My `table` has rows that contain Projects, and BillCodes as DropDowns**. If `disable` an select option in dropdown, then it does not POST to server!

`$('.timecodeDdlId').find('option[value=' + $(this).val() + ']').prop('disabled', true);` works **but disabled** does not POST selected value to server

---

**Question**: How can I **prevent duplicate selection in second dropdown**? While I found answers on So [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4944330/6085193). However, they fail - and dont POSTING to server**.  `$('.timecodeDdlId').find('option[value=' + $(this).val() + ']').prop('disabled', true);` does not POST to server side.

---

RENDERED HTML Snippet Table, with DropDown Rows

```
 <tbody id="TS">
 <tr class="rowCss"> //ROW 1

<td>
  <span class="project">
    <select class="form-control projectcodeid" id="Records_0__SelectedProjectFromList" name="Records[0].SelectedProjectFromList">
      <option value="">Modeling</option>
      <option value="1">Ventosanzap</option>
      <option value="2">Modeling</option>
    </select>
  </span>
</td>
<td>
  <input type="hidden" name="Records.Index" value="0">
    <span class="billingcodeCss">
      <select class="form-control timecodeDdlId" id="Records_0__SelectedBillingCodesFromList" name="Records[0].SelectedBillingCodesFromList">
        <option value="">Budget-070</option>
        <option selected="selected" value="5">Budget-070  </option>
        <option value="6">Budget-784                                        </option>
      </select>
    </span>
  </td>
</tr>
<tr class="rowCss"> //ROW 2

  <td>
    <span class="project">
      <select class="form-control projectcodeid" id="Records_0__SelectedProjectFromList" name="Records[0].SelectedProjectFromList">
        <option value="">Modeling</option>
        <option value="1">Ventosanzap</option>
        <option value="2">Modeling</option>
      </select>
    </span>
  </td>
  <td>
    <input type="hidden" name="Records.Index" value="0">
      <span class="billingcodeCss">
        <select class="form-control timecodeDdlId" id="Records_0__SelectedBillingCodesFromList" name="Records[0].SelectedBillingCodesFromList">
          <option value="">Budget-070</option>
          <option selected="selected" value="5">Budget-070  </option>   // HOW TO PREVENT DUPLICATE AND STILL POST TO SERVER

          <option value="6">Budget-784                                        </option>
        </select>
      </span>
    </td>
  </tr> //

</tbody>
```

---

JAVASCRIPT OnChange to prevent duplicate selections

```
    //Disable other previous/next selected TimeCodes On Change
    $('#TS').on('change', '.timecodeDdlId', function () { //baby name check

        //Is this the correct dropdown we are selecting why not $this?
        var allSelectedBillingCodeDropDown = $('#TS .timecodeDdlId option:selected');
        var thisBillingSelectedDropDown = $(this);
        var currentSelectBillingCode = $(this).val();
        // get exisiting vlaue seelections
        $.each(allSelectedBillingCodeDropDown, function (index, item) {
            if ($(item).val() == currentSelectBillingCode)
            {
                debugger;
                // remove this selection
                //selectedBillingCodeDropDown.find('option[value=' + currentSelectBillingCode + ']').remove();
                thisBillingSelectedDropDown.find('option[value=' + currentSelectBillingCode + ']').remove();
                //alert userd
                alert('Billing code cannot be the same');
                return false;
            }

            // $('#select_id').find('option[value=' + foo + ']').remove();
            //item.remove all

        });
```

---

[image]

Comment: question... what do you get from your browser console if you try to get this `$('.timecodeDdlId').find('option[value=' + value + ']')`... do you even get a value?... disabled elements do not post to the server (or at least I'm never able to get it's value from the request) ... so maybe you can try to add a style rule instead of disabling it?, and remove the `pointer-events` from the option so it cannot be selected? just some ideas.

Comment: @DavidEspino can you share a snippet on how to disable with the style element.

Comment: Well I have another answer that would avoid the pointer events for it...  Is just a css prop that you can set to see if it fits your needs. Here: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6657545/setting-attribute-disabled-on-a-span-element-does-not-prevent-click-events/27723966#27723966

Comment: @DavidEspino its an interesting approach, but please where there is no pointer involved, like a keyboard tab its failing.

Answer (score 1):

```
You can try this way

    $(document).ready(function() {
          $("select").on('hover', function () {
                $previousValue = $(this).val();
            }).change(function() {
                $("select").not(this).find("option[value='"+ $(this).val() + "']").attr('disabled', true);
                $("select").not(this).find("option[value='"+ $previousValue + "']").attr('disabled', false);
            });
        });

    $("#confirm-form").submit(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $("select").find("option").removeAttr('disabled');
        document.getElementById('confirm-form').submit();
    });
```